# MATLAB programmatic GUI listbox value and data it refers to

Tags: matlab, user-interface, listbox

I am making a GUI programmatically and have run into a small question regarding the uicontrol listbox and the data each 'value' or 'string' refers to. I feel this question will best be illustrated with some code. The code at the end of this question illustrates my question.

If you run this example, select all 5 files from the left listbox and press 'Button1', you will see them go into the right listbox. You can then select 1, or several of the files in the right list box and press 'Button2' and MATLAB will output the correct files names. All is fine here.

If you close and re run the program, and just select file1, file3, and file5, pressing Button1 will make them go into the right list box again. This is where my problem is: If you select all of the files now in the right list box (file1, file3, file3), and press Button2, matlab outputs file1, file2, and file3... not file1, file3 and file5 as I would like.

Now I understand why this is happening, because in a list box its `value` property starts at 1 and increases, and the underlying data in the Cell `DataSet` remains ordered file1 to file5... So `value` 1 2 3 refers to `DataSet{1}` `DataSet{2}` `DataSet{3}`...

What would be the best way to overcome this problem? I would like to add that for my actual GUI the file names might not always be so obviously named.

```
classdef example < handle

    properties
        Figure;
        Button1;
        Button2;
        ListBox1;
        ListBox2;

        DataSet = {};
    end

    methods
        function obj = example()
            create(obj);
            makeUpData(obj);
        end

        function create(obj)
            obj.Figure = figure('Position',[300 300 640 640]);

            obj.Button1 = uicontrol('Style','pushbutton','String','Button1',...
                'Position',[240 260 80 40],'Callback',@obj.button1CB);

            obj.Button2 = uicontrol('Style','pushbutton','String','Button2',...
                'Position',[510 260 80 40],'Callback',@obj.button2CB);

            obj.ListBox1 = uicontrol('Style','listbox','String','',...
                'Position',[50 250 145 100],'Max',3);

            obj.ListBox2 = uicontrol('Style','listbox','String','',...
                'Position',[350 250 145 100],'Max',3);
        end

        function makeUpData(obj)
            obj.DataSet = {'file1' 'file2' 'file3' 'file4' 'file5'};
            obj.ListBox1.String = obj.DataSet;
        end

        function button1CB(obj,hObject,eventdata)
            CurrentNum = get(obj.ListBox1,'Value');
            NameListBox1 = get(obj.ListBox1,'String');
            NewName = obj.ListBox2.String;
            for i = 1:numel(CurrentNum)
                NewName{end+1} = [NameListBox1{CurrentNum(i)}];
            end
            obj.ListBox2.String = NewName;
        end

        function button2CB(obj,hObject,eventdata)
            CurrentNum = get(obj.ListBox2,'Value')
            for i = 1:numel(CurrentNum)
                obj.DataSet{CurrentNum(i)}
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this application I would recommend storing your data in a [structure](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html) rather than a cell array. This will allow you to utilize [dynamic field references](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/13/use-dynamic-field-references/) to access your data and not worry about converting from a file name to an index in your cell array.

I've modified your `properties` definition:

```
properties
    Figure;
    Button1;
    Button2;
    ListBox1;
    ListBox2;

    DataSet = struct;
end
```

Your `makeUpData` definition:

```
 function makeUpData(obj)
    dummydata = {'file1' 'file2' 'file3' 'file4' 'file5'};
    for ii = 1:length(dummydata)
        obj.DataSet.(dummydata{ii}) = dummydata{ii};
    end
    obj.ListBox1.String = fieldnames(obj.DataSet);
end
```

And your `button2CB` definition:

```
function button2CB(obj,hObject,eventdata)
    listboxvalues = get(obj.ListBox2, 'String');
    CurrentNum = get(obj.ListBox2,'Value');
    for i = 1:numel(CurrentNum)
        obj.DataSet.(listboxvalues{CurrentNum(i)})
    end
end
```

Now your selection returns:

```
ans =

file1


ans =

file3


ans =

file5
```

As expected.

Comment: Thanks, I have changed the data structure of my original program to a struct and this is working perfectly. Just one minor alteration I had to do was change it from `obj.DataSet.(listboxvalues{i})` to `obj.DataSet.(listboxvalues{CurrentNum(i)})`, Otherwise it displays the first file no matter if you select just the 2nd or 3rd. Perfect solution though thanks.

Comment: @SteveHatcher oops, I changed the function slightly and forgot to adjust the loop. I'll fix it in a second.

Answer (score 1):

You can change callback function of `Button2` as follows, using `ismember` to get the corresponded index in the `obj.DataSet`:

```
function button2CB(obj,hObject,eventdata)
    selected = cellstr(get(obj.ListBox2, 'String'));
    referred = ismember(obj.DataSet, selected);
    obj.DataSet(referred)
    obj.DataSet{referred}
end
```

Comment: Hi scmg. Thanks for your solution. This does indeed print out just the filenames that are in listbox2, but I was a bit stuck as to how then take it to the next step and loop through just the selected files (eg just file 1 & 3 for instance). I ended up changing my data structures to a struct, but your solution will probably have worked if I wanted to keep them as cell arrays.